# Relationship between law of total covariance and partial correlation

Tags: covariance, partial-correlation

Law of total covariance says that:

$$Cov(X,Y) = E[Cov(X, Y | Z)] + Cov(E[X|Z], E[Y|Z])$$

Then, it seems like partial correlation may be defined as:

$$\frac{E[Cov(X, Y | Z)]}{Cov(X, Y)}$$

And this is because $Cov(E[X|Z], E[Y|Z])$ gives covariance between values of $X$ and $Y$ as regressed on $Z$ and $E[Cov(X, Y | Z)]$ is then the covariance between the residuals left after the two regressions.

Is my reasoning correct or do I miss something?

EDIT.

It turns out that the formula I presented is not exactly partial correlation since $Cov([X|Z], E[Y|Z])$ measures linear association between arbitrary, even nonlinear, regressions of $X$ and $Y$ on $Z$, while partial correlation measures linear correlation between $X$ and $Y$ after removing linear association with $Z$.

However, now I wonder if the formula I presented may be considered a more general variation of partial correlation that measures linear association between $X$ and $Y$ after partialing out dependence on $Z$ of arbitrary functional form. In other words, it seems it should be equivalent to the correlation between residuals of arbitrary nonlinear regressions (regression of type I) of $X$ and $Y$ on $Z$.

Comment: Remind that the *partial* correlation is not the same thing as the *conditional* correlation. Indeed, $E[X|Z]$ and $E[Y|Z]$ are not necessarily linear in $Z$, while the partial correlation is defined in terms of *linear* regressions. Moreover, the denominator is for both coefficients a product of standard deviations (ordinary or conditional), not a covariance.

Comment: Yes, you're right about linearity. Once I gave some more though to the problem, then I also realised that E[X|Z] and E[Y|Z] may be nonlinear while partial correlation is defined in terms of linear relationships only.

Comment: However, in regard to the denominator I think that you're not right. I know that correlation have the product of standard deviations in the denominator, but it is easy to see that if we try decompose a correlations (covariance divided by the product of standard deviations) then both E[Cov(X,Y|Z)] and Cov(X,Y) would have products of standard deviations in the denominators so they would cancel each other out.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what you want to do: define a new 
association coefficient? Note that your proposal is undefined
when $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, a condition that does not relate
to $Z$. The conditional (partial) correlation are undefined when
$X$ or $Y$ is a function (linear function) of $Z$.

Comment: Cov([E[X|Z], E[Y|Z]) measures linear association between arbitrary and thus possibly nonlinear regression of X and Y on Z. Then E[Cov(X, Y | Z)] corresponds to this part of the total covariance that is left after partialing out the association between the two regressions (fitted values). Then the ratio I proposed take values on the interval [-1, 1] and measures a specific kind of linear relationship, so it seems to be a kind of correlation. But of course your remark is correct: it is not defined for Cov(X, Y) = 0.

Comment: Ok, now I see my mistake thanks to your remarks. First of all, it is not guaranteed that the ratio I proposed wil be normalised to take values in [-1, 1], because E[Cov(X, Y| Z]) may be, for instance, strongly negative, while Cov(E[X|Z], E[Y|Z]) strongly positive, and thus Cov(X, Y) would close to zero, and in this case the ratio would be much higher/lower than -1 or 1. And as a result, the ratio may not be considered a measure of correlation. I will then soon delete the question, if no other users find it important to add anything to the discussion. Thanks once again for hints.